# Is it possible to merge Skype and Windows Live contacts?

Tags: skype, windows-live-messenger, contacts, instant-messaging

I have both Skype and Windows Live Messenger accounts. Then, Microsoft told me to merge, so I did and only use Skype for both. I also have contacts on both lists, and they now show up twice; one representing Messenger, and the other representing Skype. **Is there a way to merge these two sets of contacts, so each contact shows up *only* once?**

Comment: While not the best solution if you have access to Outlook you could import the contacts then you might be able to use an Outlook add-on to merge duplicate contacts.  You could then delete all your contacts.  Another possible solution is to use outlook.com and see if it can merge duplicate contacts.  At this point a Skype and WLM contact should be one in the same.

Comment: I'm also interested about this, but also after months from the merge, contacts are still displayed separately.